# 端末上の emacs が、シェルから書き換える環境変数は何？

Tags: emacs

素の emacs を実行しても (`emacs -q`)、 TERM 環境変数はもともとが何に設定されていても、結果として `dumb` になります。 `M-x getenv <RET> TERM <RET>` で確認しました。

普段 emacs を環境として使っていて、意図しない環境変数の書き換えがあると、無駄な罠に将来はまると思っています。

質問:

- 端末上の emacs が、親のシェルから引き継がない環境変数は、 `TERM` 以外にありますか?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「Emacs起動時に親プロセスから継承された環境変数の一覧」と「現在の環境変数の一覧」は[initial-environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html#index-initial_002denvironment)と[process-environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html#index-process_002denvironment)で参照できます。中身はどちらも文字列のリスト `("PATH=/bin:/usr/bin..." "SHELL=/bin/bash" ...)` です。

この2つのリストの差分をとってみると環境変数`TERM`だけが更新されているようです。

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-set-difference initial-environment process-environment)
;;=> ("TERM=dumb")
```

また[ソースコードを検索](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/search?l=c&q=xputenv&utf8=%E2%9C%93)してみると`EMACS_HEAP_EXEC=true`, `GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS=1`などが環境によっては更新されるようです。

---

これとは別に、`M-x shell`でシェルを起動すると以下の2つの環境変数が上書きされます。(おそらく通常のシェルと区別する目的があると思うのですが、詳しくはわかりません)

- `EMACS=t`
- `INSIDE_EMACS=24.5.1,comint` (数字はEmacsのバージョン番号)

Answer (score 7):

emacs process の環境変数は `process-environment` 変数に保持されています。

> **process-environment**
>   　List of overridden environment variables for subprocesses to inherit.

```
(require 'cl)
(find-if #'(lambda (e) (string-match "^TERM=" e)) process-environment)
=> "TERM=dumb"
```

ただし、一つだけ例外があって、それは `DISPLAY` 環境変数です。

```
(find-if #'(lambda (e) (string-match "^DISPLAY=" e)) process-environment)
=> nil

(getenv "DISPLAY")
=> ":0.0"
(let (process-environment) (getenv "DISPLAY"))
=> ":0.0"
(let (process-environment) (start-process "env" (current-buffer) "env"))
=> DISPLAY=:0.0
```

`process-environment` 変数を `nil`(empty list)に bind しても `DISPLAY` 環境変数がセットされています。

ソースコードを確認してみると、`process-environment` に `DISPLAY` 環境変数が存在しない場合は `initial-environment` から取り出しています。

**emacs/src/callproc.c**

```c
static bool
getenv_internal (const char *var, ptrdiff_t varlen, char **value, ...)
{
  /* Try to find VAR in Vprocess_environment first.  */
  if (getenv_internal_1 (var, varlen, value, valuelen, Vprocess_environment))
    return *value ? 1 : 0;

  /* For DISPLAY try to get the values from the frame or the initial env. */
  if (strcmp (var, "DISPLAY") == 0)
    {
                :
      /* If still not found, Look for DISPLAY in Vinitial_environment.  */
      if (getenv_internal_1 (var, varlen, value, valuelen, Vinitial_environment))
        return *value ? 1 : 0;
    }
            :

int
child_setup (int in, ...)
{
           :
  for (tem = Vprocess_environment;
       CONSP (tem) && STRINGP (XCAR (tem));
       tem = XCDR (tem))
    {
      if (strncmp (SSDATA (XCAR (tem)), "DISPLAY", 7) == 0
          && (SDATA (XCAR (tem)) [7] == '\0'
              || SDATA (XCAR (tem)) [7] == '='))
         /* DISPLAY is specified in process-environment.  */
           :
    }

  /* If not provided yet, use the frame's DISPLAY.  */
  if (NILP (display))
    {
      Lisp_Object tmp = Fframe_parameter (selected_frame, Qdisplay);
      if (!STRINGP (tmp) && CONSP (Vinitial_environment))
        /* If still not found, Look for DISPLAY in Vinitial_environment.  */
        tmp = Fgetenv_internal (build_string ("DISPLAY"),
                                Vinitial_environment);
           :


/* If we have a PWD envvar, pass one down,
   but with corrected value.  */
if (egetenv ("PWD"))
  *new_env++ = pwd_var;
```

> **initial-environment**
>   　List of environment variables inherited from the parent process.

この parent process は emacs を起動したプロセス(例えばシェルプロセス)です。

それから、先のソースコードに `PWD` 環境変数を再設定している部分があります。

```
(let ((default-directory "/tmp"))
   (start-process "pwd" (current-buffer) "printenv" "PWD"))
=> /tmp
```

なお、`process-environment` はユーザ側で変更することが可能です。

```
(let ((process-environment
       (cons "TERM=xterm" process-environment)))
  (list
   (mapcan #'(lambda (e) (and (string-match "^TERM=" e) (list e)))
           process-environment)
   (getenv "TERM")))
=> (("TERM=xterm" "TERM=dumb") "xterm")
```

同じ環境変数が存在する場合は、先に設定された値が有効になります。

**追記**

`term-mode` での環境変数の追加(`process-environment`へのpush)は以下の部分で行われています。端末制御に必要な環境変数なのだと思います。

**emacs/25.1.50/lisp/term.el**

```
(let ((process-environment
       (nconc
        (list
         (format "TERM=%s" term-term-name)
         (format "TERMINFO=%s" data-directory)
         (format term-termcap-format "TERMCAP="
                 term-term-name term-height term-width)

         ;; This is for backwards compatibility with Bash 4.3 and earlier.
         ;; Remove this hack once Bash 4.4-or-later is common, because
         ;; it breaks './configure' of some packages that expect it to
         ;; say where to find EMACS.
         (format "EMACS=%s (term:%s)" emacs-version term-protocol-version)

         (format "INSIDE_EMACS=%s,term:%s" emacs-version term-protocol-version)
         (format "LINES=%d" term-height)
         (format "COLUMNS=%d" term-width))
        process-environment))
```

Answer (score 3):

`process-environment` で emacs-24.1 ソース内部を `grep` してみました。
外部プロセスを起動する系の `elisp` はかなりのものが環境変数を上書きしているようです。
一部のみ抜粋してみましょう。

`emacs-24.1/lisp/man.el`
`COLUMNS=999`
`man` コマンドのカラム数を 999 に設定し emacs 内部で整形させるためのもののようです。

`emacs-24.1/lisp/progmodes/grep.el`
`TERM=emacs-grep GREP_OPTIONS+=--color=auto GREP_COLORS=...`
GNU grep のときに色指定を行っている様子

`emacs-24.1/lisp/vc/vc-dispatcher.el`
`LC_MESSAGES=C`

`emacs-24.1/lisp/vc/vc-hg.el`
`TERM=dumb LANGUAGE=C`

`emacs-24.1/lisp/vc/vc-git.el`
`PAGER=`

最初から NLS 対応な vcs ツールは英語モードで起動している様子
PAGER 対応なツールは PAGER なしで起動している様子

`term.el` はもう指摘があるの省略

この辺を気にするかしないかは人それぞれでしょうか・・・